# Sql Server Split up the column

Tags: sql-server, split

I have a table contact_add. I have one column City which contains (MANGALORE-575001) I want a query to split up the City and Pincode in SQL server. If Substring Expression, start and length have to be given, which may differ for each city

EXAMPLE:

```
Mangalore-123456 
Kannur-6542 
kochi-78954 
Goa-12
```

I want a query to split up the name and pincode into two columns like below

```
city      Pincode 
--------- ------- 
Mangalore 123456 
Kannur    6542 
Kochi     78954 
Goa       12
```

Comment: is it always "Cityname-6153135" so string dash number? if that is the case you can just get the index of the dash and use substrings once you know that one, also it's always suggested to give more sample data if you ask a question so people will be able to help better

Comment: Hi Jeremy,

I have a table contact_add of which a column is City.

Example
Mangalore-123456
Kannur-6542
kochi-78954
Goa-12

I want a query to split up the name and pincode into two columns like below

city  Pincode
--------- -------
Mangalore  123456
Kannur  6542
Kochi  78954
Goa         12

Comment: if all your records have city-number then you can just split the string on the '-'

Comment: @Aju - please [edit] your question and add your example (note that if you want to show tabular data, usually formatting it as code (`{}` button)) keeps the formatting well.

Answer (score 2):

TRY this:

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',city)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(city,1,CHARINDEX('-',city)-1) 
         ELSE city end City, 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('-',city)>0  THEN SUBSTRING(city,CHARINDEX('-',city)+1,len(city))  
         ELSE NULL END as pincode
FROM Contact_add
```

city = column name  at line2

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
select substring('MANGALORE-575001',0,CHARINDEX('-','MANGALORE-575001')), substring('MANGALORE-575001',CHARINDEX('-','MANGALORE-575001')+1,len('MANGALORE-575001'))
```